PaperMC plugin Send player to other Server
I have a small Server Network with a Velocity proxy, and I don't know how to send player to another Server with a plugin that runs on the backend server?
I'm looking for a Dependance or Method I have to use to fix this problem.
Sorry for my bad English.

Hello, welcome on StackOverflow. Your question is off-topic as it's not programming related

so programming a plugin in intellij isnt programming ? how can that be?

If you're doing your own plugin, I suggest you to read [ask], take the [tour]. Then [edit] your post to add all details about where you are stuck, also did you check the documentation ?
